# Coefficient of $x^9$ in the Product

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Find the Coefficient of $x^9$ in $$G(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{100})$$

My Try:
$$G(x)=P(x)(1+x^{10})(1+x^{11})\cdots(1+x^{100})=P(x)(1+O(x^{10}))$$ Hence Coefficient of $x^9$ in $G(x)$ is Coefficient of $x^9$ in $P(x)$ where $$P(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^9)=R(x)+x^9R(x)$$  So Coefficient of $x^9$ in $P(x)$ is $1$+coeff of $x^9$ in $ R(x)$ where $$R(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^8)$$

But the method is becoming lengthy. Can i have any good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as other answers, the coefficient of $x^9$ is the number of ways to express $9$ into sum of distinct integers.

And this remind me of Euler's **Partition function** and the **Pentagonal number theorem**.

Euler has proved that for number of ways to express an integer into sum of distinct integers, $q(n)$, there is a recurrence relation:

$$q(n)=a_k+q(n-1)+q(n-2)-q(n-5)-q(n-7)+...$$

where $q(n)=0$ if $n<0$ and $a_k$ is $(−1)^m$ if $\exists m\in{\Bbb{N}},k = 3m^2 − m $ and is $0$ otherwise.

So you may reduce $q(9)$ into $q(8)+q(7)-q(4)-q(2)$ and to reduce further to make it simplier to calculate. For instance it is easy to check value of $q(0), q(1)$, etc for small value of $n$.

For more straightforward way, you may just check the sequence A000009 in OEIS. And we get $q(9)=8$

Reference:
**Wiki**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

**OEIS**
https://oeis.org/A000009

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The desired coefficient is the number of ways to express $9$ as a sum of distinct positive integers. Since $1+2+3+4>9$, you need only consider sums of at most three integers.

Comment: Congrats Brian on 300k!! You are the best!

Comment: @Anonaki: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take some of the terms say like 1, $x^1 , x^3 , x^5 $ then their product will be $x^{9}$ with coefficient 1, similarly for other $x^9$ terms you need terms whose products give $x^9$, i.e no of ways to express 9 as a product of integers (order does not matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to find the different ways to decompose $9$ into different integers:
$$ 9 = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k, \, \, k\in \mathbb{N}, \, 1 \le a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_k$$
Since those would be the only possible ways a monome in the developed expression of $G(x)$ to have degree of $9$.